# Proving that in-order traversal of binary search tree is sorted (without induction)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Can I prove that traversing binary search tree in-order yields a sorted progression of values, without using induction?

This isn't really a homework question.

Comment: It follows from the definition of a binary search tree. In a BST, the left node is less than the root, and the right node is greater than or equal to the root. So if you recursively go left node, parent, right node, then you get the nodes in ascending order. If you don't, then you don't have a binary search tree.

Comment: You could probably use proof by contradiction in this case.

Comment: I understand it intuitively, but I really have no idea how to prove it more formally besides using induction. @Rafe, could you write it out explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my sketch of a proof by contradiction.

Our goal is to show that in-order traversal of a finite ordered binary tree produces an ordered sequence.

To prove this by contradiction, we start by assuming the opposite: that there exists some ordered binary tree such that its in-order traversal yields a non-ordered sequence.  Since our trees are finite, there must be a minimal such instance.  Let's call this tree T.

Now, T cannot be a singleton (i.e., just a leaf) because the traversal of a singleton yields a sequence of length one, which is trivially ordered.

Therefore T must have some shape, L-x-R where x is a vertex value connecting left and right subtrees L and R respectively.

Since T is minimal and ordered, L and R must be ordered trees whose in-order traversals produce ordered sequences.  Moreover, we know that all items in L can be no greater than x and all items in R can be no smaller than x.  Now, the traversal of T is [T] = [L] ++ [x] ++ [R].  But this sequence must be ordered, which contradicts our initial assumption concerning T.

Therefore no such T exists, hence in-order traversal of any ordered binary tree must produce an ordered sequence.

Howzat?

Comment: That's a fantastic answer @Rafe :), its really easy to understand the insigt you have given, the proof kinda uses induction but inside a contradiction :). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AnkitSablok Very kind of you!  I don't think the proof uses induction, which requires a base case and an inductive step.  This just uses the fact that finite binary trees are enumerable.